# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation when using an Azure service principal to create Azure resources

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, teamcity

I would like to use a service principal account to run a Powershell script that creates Azure resources, as suggested in [this article about doing so when provisioning via TeamCity](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/12/azure-service-principal.html)

I am able to create the service principal and assign it the 'Owner' role on the subscription, so in theory it should have rights to do anything in the Azure account. (I will adjust the rights later to just what is required by the principal.) The commands are basically the following:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount # using my Azure admin account
$azureAdApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "Deploy" -HomePage "https://deploy" -IdentifierUris "https://deploy" -Password "password"
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Owner -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId
$subscription = Get-AzureRmSubscription
$creds = Get-Credential
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $subscription.TenantId
```

However, when I then run a Powershell script that provisions resources, I get the following warnings when creating a Key Vault:

- Insufficient privileges to complete the operation
- Access policy is not set. No user or application have access permission to use this vault. Please use Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy to set access policies

I don't get these warnings when creating the Key Vault via my own admin account. How do I give a service principal sufficient privileges to be able to create resources in an Azure subscription without getting permissions issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have created a Service Principal and not a user, and are trying to interact with Azure Vault. (everything else should work as expected)

As a user you would have access to Vault, but because you're accessing it as a Service Principal it is expecting to find a relevant Access Policy.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried adding access rights for the Service Principal to the Key Vault and that seems to have worked -- the principal can add secrets to the vault and then read them. You say everything else should work as expected, but interestingly I can't use the Principal account to query for principal info: 'Get-AzureRmAdServicePrincipal -SearchString "someString"'. The error is 'Access denied to the specified API version'.

Comment: @stevejay ahh yes! there is that one too - you need to use MSOL to add it to AD - I can't remember the command, but there's questions about it on here

Comment: Thanks for the extra info; I'll look into it.

Comment: @stevejay Hi, Steve! I am facing the same issue when query for principal information after log in as the service principal. How did you solve it?